# pandas daily average, pandas.resample

Tags: python, pandas, mean, numeric, resampling

I have a csv file similar to this

```
Date,Temp1,Temp2

23-Oct-09 01:00:00,21.1,22.3

23-Oct-09 04:00:00,22.3,23.8

23-Oct-09 07:00:00,21.4,21.3

23-Oct-09 10:00:00,21.5,21.6

23-Oct-09 13:00:00,22.3,23.8

23-Oct-09 16:00:00,21.4,21.3

23-Oct-09 19:00:00,21.1,22.3

23-Oct-09 22:00:00,21.4,21.3

24-Oct-09 01:00:00,22.3,23.8

24-Oct-09 04:00:00,22.3,23.8

24-Oct-09 07:00:00,21.1,22.3

24-Oct-09 10:00:00,22.3,23.8

24-Oct-09 13:00:00,21.1,22.3

24-Oct-09 16:00:00,22.3,23.8

24-Oct-09 19:00:00,21.1,22.3

24-Oct-09 22:00:00,22.3,23.8
```

I have read the data with:

```
df=pd.read_csv('data.csv', index_col=0)
```

and converted the index to date time

```
df.index=pd.to_datetime(df.index)
```

Now I want to take the mean of each daily temperature, I have been trying to use pd.resample as below, but have been receiving errors. I've read the pandas.resample docs and numerous examples on here and am still at a loss...

```
df_avg = df.resample('D', how = 'mean')
```

> DataError: No numeric types to aggregate

I would like df_avg to be a dataframe with a datetime index and the two 2 columns. I am using pandas 0.17.1 and python 3.5.2, any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need convert `string` columns to `float` first:

```
#add parameter parse_dates for convert to datetime first column
df=pd.read_csv('data.csv', index_col=0, parse_dates=[0])

df['Temp1'] = df.Temp1.astype(float)
df['Temp2'] = df.Temp2.astype(float)

df_avg = df.resample('D').mean()
```

---

If `astype` return `error`, problem is there are some non numeric values. So you need use [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html) with `errors='coerce'` - then all 'problematic' values are converted to `NaN`:

```
df['Temp1'] = pd.to_numeric(df.Temp1, errors='coerce')
df['Temp2'] = pd.to_numeric(df.Temp2, errors='coerce')
```

You can also check all rows with problematic values with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
print df[pd.to_numeric(df.Temp1, errors='coerce').isnull()]
print df[pd.to_numeric(df.Temp2, errors='coerce').isnull()]
```

Comment: Note that this method is deprecated and the resample code should now be df.resample('D').mean()